# Control stream in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

With the stream API, I can write a RichCoFlatMapFunction that accept a control stream and a data stream, the control stream contains the elements for start or stop or change parameter of the calculation, I know I can store the current control settings in states, and check the value when process data stream.

But what's the way to do the similar thing with Flink SQL?
I cannot use join as data stream and control stream is not able to join together.

The solution we come up with is to store the control settings by application itself.
The idea is:

1. **Broadcast** the control stream to a map operator, and store the control settings to a java singleton objects in its map() method, as the map operator will run with the default parallelism, **we assume** that it will run on all JVMs for that job, so that we make sure every JVM will initialize and keep updating the control settings in the singleton object.
2. With SQL, for every UDAF or UDF we can access the control settings through accessing the java singleton objects.

But I am not sure if my assumption is correct and this is a feasible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is a good idea. SQL was not designed for such use cases. Instead a SQL query is optimized and executed as specified. Changing the behavior of a query is not intended. Besides the design perspective, it would also not perform well because you would need do remote state look-ups to distributed queryable state for each record that you process. This adds of course latency.

To me your use case sounds more like an application than SQL query. For that the DataStream API would be the right choice. What you can do, is to embed SQL (or Table API) queries into an application, i.e., do the pre and post processing with SQL and have an operator with an control/data stream pattern in the middle.

Comment: Get your point, but I can't understand why it adds latency. Even with DataStream API, we still have to get the current control settings from states for each record from data stream. And we don't need a remote lookup as every JVM will have a cluster singleton object for local query.

Comment: I thought about to mix DataStreamp API and SQL, but looks not easy to do, my requirement is that when we receive a stop message from control stream, then we stop everything including the pre-processing, so we will need to find a way to notify a control stream to the SQL part, unless we don't use SQL at all.

Comment: Singletons are in general not a good idea. You rely on the fact that two different operations are executed on the same JVM. IMO, this design won't work. Regarding mixing the APIs, you could have a filter as the first operator before the first SQL query.